# Customize Form Error Messages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message

So, I'm trying to come up with a way to customize the error messages in `form_for`'s. The most elegant way to do this, in my opinion, would be *inside* the text area itself. So far, any method I've tried messes up the form completely. Please share your thoughts and methods. 
Simple form:

```
 <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %><br> 
 <%= f.text_field :name, size: 30 %>

 <%= f.label :password, 'Password' %><br>
 <%= f.password_field :password, size: 30 %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm' %><br>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 30 %>

<%= f.submit %>
```

As you can see, no errors mentioned here since I've added an initializer as follows:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
errors = Array(instance.error_message).join(',')

if html_tag =~ /^<label/
    html_tag
    else
    %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;#{errors}</span>).html_safe
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper method

```
def errors_for(model, attribute)
  if model.errors[attribute].present?
    content_tag :span, :class => 'error_explanation' do
      model.errors[attribute].join(", ")
    end
  end
end
```

And in view:

```
  <%= lesson_form.text_field :description %><br />
  <%= errors_for @lesson, :description %>
```

Comment: It doesn't let me since I just signed up.

Answer (score 1):

My version of the common solution:

The helper method:

```
def errors_for(model, attribute)
  if model.errors[attribute].any?
    content_tag :span, class: 'error' do
      attribute.to_s.humanize + " " + model.errors[attribute].to_sentence
    end
  end
end
```

The view:

```
<%= errors_for @user, :name %>
```

What you get:

```
"Name can't be blank and is too short (minimum is 2 characters)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of showing error messages:

```
    def error_messages_for object
      error_content = ''
      if object.errors.any?
       error_content += content_tag(:div, :id => 'error_explanation',  :class => 'alert alert-error') do
        content_tag(:h3, "#{pluralize(object.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this #{object.class.name.downcase} from being saved:") +
        content_tag(:ul, class: 'unstyled') do
          object.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            concat content_tag(:li, "#{message}") if message.present?
          end
        end
      end
    end
    error_content.html_safe
  end
    Inside views use this helper:
    <%= error_messages_for @sample %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Still  a better can be using `full_messages_for`:

In you helper define:

```
def error_message_for(record, field)
  record.full_messages_for(field).join(",")
end
```

If you do not want to show full message, you can use:

```
  record.errors.get(field).join(",")
```

And then in your view:

```
<%= errors_message_for @lesson, :description %>
```

Comment: That works great. Only thing is, how do I make the css form box extend automatically with the form? (that is, when the errors appear). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: "extend automatically"? couldn't get you there.

Comment: It wouldn't let me attach a screenshot. What I meant was once the errors appear, the form css "box" would need to extend, too, to accommodate the errors. In general, the errors in rails forms seem to be rather buggy, would I be better off doing this in JavaScript?